# Node - Database query callback not firing

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

This may be a stupid question but I was not able to find an answer.
My db query (node -> PostgreSQL) is not firing the callback when the query function itself is called from another callback like this:

**routes.js**

```
router.post("/getsheet/", (req, res) => {

    googleAPI.getSheet(googleToken, req.body.sheetid).then((invoices) => {

        templateData.sheetData = invoices;
        templateData.sheetData.length = invoices.length;

        // When sheet is received, db query runs but it's callback won't
        // function takes an array and index
        db.query(invoices, 1).then((db_results) => {
            console.log(db_results);
            res.redirect("/");
        }).catch((db_error) => {
            console.error(db_error)
            res.redirect("/");
        });

    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
});
```

**db.js**

```
const query = (data, index) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // console log fires but not the callback function so it does not resolve or reject
    console.log("... querying index ... " + index + " customer: " + data[index].name);
    client.query(`SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customer_number=${data[index].customer_id};`, (err, res) => {
            // does not run this block
            if (!err) {
                resolve(res);
            } else {
                return reject(err);
            }
    });
});
```

}

Thanks! :)

Comment: Your code in `routes.js` doesn't even call the `query` function you show after. Something is missing. And in general, instead of converting `pg` library into promises, it is better to use [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) ;)

Comment: These snippets are part of larger code and routes.js of course requires db.js in variable "db". Client connect and end are before and after query -function.
Sorry I left those points out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already established a connection?  You'd need to do that first before trying to run a query.  See an example here:
http://mherman.org/blog/2015/02/12/postgresql-and-nodejs/#.WeJpJWhSyUk

```
  pg.connect(connectionString, (err, client, done) => {
    // Handle connection errors
    if(err) {
      done();
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).json({success: false, data: err});
    }
    // SQL Query > Select Data
    const query = client.query('SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY id ASC;');
    // Stream results back one row at a time
    query.on('row', (row) => {
      results.push(row);
    });
    // After all data is returned, close connection and return results
    query.on('end', () => {
      done();
      return res.json(results);
    });
  });
```

Also, I'd highly recommend you use `npm pg-promise`.  Will simplify your life.

Lastly, you're also missing the point of promises.  I'd encourage you to use the newer async/await.  However if you don't want to and/or can't, at least see why you're just getting back into a callback hell... promises are in place to help reduce all the call back nesting.  Really you should reduce the nest level of your promises, like so:

```
router.post("/getsheet/", (req, res) => {

    googleAPI.getSheet(googleToken, req.body.sheetid).then((invoices) => {

        templateData.sheetData = invoices;
        templateData.sheetData.length = invoices.length;

        // When sheet is received, db query runs but it's callback won't
        // function takes an array and index
        return db.query(invoices, 1);
    }).then((db_results) => {
        console.log(db_results);
        res.redirect("/");
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        res.redirect("/");
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, the db query works and connection is established before the query-function. Thanks I will try your advice and let you know how it went! :)

Comment: I marked this as the answer since you pointed me to right direction. Thanks! :)
BTW: I ended up using the basic pg-module since it's possible to make "promise-queries" with it too like this:
`client.query(query).then((data)=>{...}).catch((e)=>{...})`

Comment: @Mulperi `pg-promise` does a lot more than just promises: https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#about